# How to combine dynamic an ImageView with TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to fill dynamic ImageViews in a LinearLayout. In addition i like to include at the top of every ImageView a TextView. Implemeting this in a static way with the xml file is no problem but I don't got any idea how to implement this problem?

For example I select 5 pictures out of the gallery and show all pics side by side. At the top of every pic you can see the name of the pic.

[EDIT]

```
LayoutInflater inflatter=(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinlayout);
// AbsoluteLayoute has got an ImageView and a TextView
AbsoluteLayout test = (AbsoluteLayout)inflatter.inflate(R.layout.test2, null, false);
TextView texttest = (TextView)test.findViewById(R.id.name);
ImageView image=(ImageView)test.findViewById(R.id.image);
texttest.setText("test");
myLayout.addView(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to make a scrollabe list, where each item in the list is a picture and a title text, right?

Have you thought about using an `ArrayAdapter` in a `ListView` and in the adapter's `getView()` you can inflate a layout file that contains an `ImageView` and a `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom layout in xml with the `ImageView` and `TextView` arranged the way you want for each item.

- AbsoluteLayout

  - TextView (above ImageView)
  - ImageView

Then, as you dynamically get the images, you inflate this custom layout using a **[LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)** and assign the `TextView` with the desired text and the `ImageView` with the desired image.  Next, you take the inflated view and add it as a child to the `LinearLayout`.  Iterate through your images and do this and you should have what the desired appearance.

Edit:  If you have many images that might require scrolling, you would have to wrap the `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView` to allow scrolling if the `LinearLayout` gets too large.

As someone else just mentioned, a ListView will take custom xml layouts and inflate them the same way using adapters and such, and it will handle scrolling for you. `ListView` **[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)** and **[example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it like the reedit in the top (please have a look) but it didn't work. Do you got an idea?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please?  The code in your edit looks good so it's hard to say what the problem might be with so little information.